# unable to create a postgres database using ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible

this is my code:

```yaml
- name: Instalation of postgresql-9.6
  apt:
    name: postgresql-9.6

- name: start postgresql service
  service: name=postgresql state=restarted enabled=yes

- name: create a database
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: managys
    encoding: UTF-8
    lc_collate: de_DE.UTF-8
    template: template0
    state: present

- name: crate user for database
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_user:
    db: template0
    name: Odoo
    password: Odoo
    priv: ALL
    state: present
```

and this is the error after executing the main playbook:

The full traceback is:

```yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_postgresql_db_payload_ce8a5D/__main__.py", line 421, in main
    db_connection = psycopg2.connect(database=maintenance_db, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"


fatal: [172.17.0.2]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "db": "managys", 
            "encoding": "UTF-8", 
            "lc_collate": "de_DE.UTF-8", 
            "lc_ctype": "", 
            "login_host": "", 
            "login_password": "", 
            "login_unix_socket": "", 
            "login_user": "postgres", 
            "maintenance_db": "postgres", 
            "name": "managys", 
            "owner": "", 
            "port": 5432, 
            "ssl_mode": "prefer", 
            "ssl_rootcert": null, 
            "state": "present", 
            "target": "", 
            "target_opts": "", 
            "template": "template0"
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "unable to connect to database: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user \"postgres\"\n"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The become_user: postgres will only work when the user with which ansible is getting executed is in the sudoers file of the target server. If not then we have to update the config file of the postgres.

The below code worked for me

```yaml
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Instalation of postgresql-9.6
      apt:
      name: postgresql-9.6

    - name: start postgresql service
      service: name=postgresql state=restarted enabled=yes

    - name: create a database
      postgresql_db:
        name: managys
        encoding: UTF-8
        template: template0
        state: present
      become_user: postgres
      become: yes
```

Comment: fatal: [172.17.0.2]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 172.17.0.2 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
    "rc": 127
}